# Is there a way to render same ChartJS component again and again in same page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, chart.js

I am working with chartJS in react. I have a single chartJs graph component which I want to use more than once. But when the page renders it only displays the first chart and the second chart is not displayed.

Below is the Chart Component I want to reuse.

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import Chart from "chart.js";


var waterFallChart;

export default function WaterFallChart(props) {

  useEffect(() => {
    if (waterFallChart) {
      waterFallChart.destroy();
    }
    const ctx = document.getElementsByClassName(props.chartClass);
    waterFallChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: "bar",
      data: {
        labels: ["sun","mon","tue","wed","thurs","fri"],
        datasets: [
          {
            label: 'Good',
            data: [10,20,30,40,50,60],
            backgroundColor: "#0058FF",
          },
          ]
      },
      options: {
      maintainAspectRatio: false,
      showAllTooltips: false,
      scales: {
        yAxes: [
          {
            ticks: {
              fontColor: "silver",
              fontSize: "12",
            },
            display: true,

            gridLines: {
              display: true,
              zeroLineColor: "white",
              zeroLineWidth: "1",
            },
          },
        ],
        xAxes: [
          {
            ticks: {
              fontColor: "silver",
              fontSize: "10",
            },
            gridLines: {
              display: true,
              color: "rgb(255,255,255, 0.2)",
              zeroLineColor: "white",
              zeroLineWidth: "2",
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      legend: {
        display: false,
      },
    },
    });
});
return (
  <React.Fragment>
    <div className="canvasParentDiv">
      <canvas className={props.chartClass} />
    </div>
  </React.Fragment>
);
}
```

And Main component which uses WaterFallChart component.

```
import React from 'react'
import WaterFallChart from './WaterFallChart'


function mainComponent() {
    return (
        <div>
            <WaterFallChart chartClass="chart1" />
            <WaterFallChart chartClass="chart2" />
            <WaterFallChart chartClass="chart2"/>
        </div>
    )
}

export default mainComponent
```

Since we can't have the same ID for the canvas, I am targeting canvas with className, Yet it just displays one chart and rest two remain hidden.

Comment: Use a `ref`: https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-mestorf-jkf2w?file=/src/WaterFallChart.js

Comment: @ChrisG I was able to display all three graphs thank you. As I will be updating the data on the graph and I must use destroy() method. Solution works perfectly without destroy method, but renders just one graph when destroy method is used.

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName(props.chartClass)` returns a node list.